# Missing return in a function expected to return 'UITableViewCell' with two tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xcode8

I use a croll view, and there are a two(or many) tableView in one view
like this

[image: layout]

but at function:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
```

It's a error

> missing return in a function expected to return 'UITableViewCell'
>   [image: error]

But I have did

`return cell`

How the error happened?

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate  {
@IBOutlet weak var scroll: UIScrollView!

@IBOutlet var recipesImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var tableView:UITableView!
@IBOutlet var tableView2: UITableView!

var recipes:Recipe!
var noodles:Recipe!
var snacks:Recipe!
var category: Int = Int()

@IBAction func segmented(sender: AnyObject) {
    switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            scroll.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x:0, y:0), animated: true)
        case 1:
            scroll.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x:375, y:0), animated: true)
        case 2:
            scroll.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x:750, y:0), animated: true)
        case 3:
            scroll.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x:1125, y:0), animated: true)


        default:
            print()
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    switch self.category {
        case 0:
            self.recipesImageView.image = UIImage(named: recipes.image)
            title = self.recipes.name
        case 1:
            self.recipesImageView.image = UIImage(named: noodles.image)
            title = self.noodles.name
        case 2:
            self.recipesImageView.image = UIImage(named: snacks.image)
            title = self.snacks.name
        case 3:
            self.recipesImageView.image = UIImage(named: noodles.image)
            title = self.noodles.name
        case 4:
            self.recipesImageView.image = UIImage(named: noodles.image)
            title = self.noodles.name
        default:
            self.recipesImageView.image = UIImage(named: recipes.image)
            title = self.recipes.name
    }

    self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 240.0/255.0, green: 240.0/255.0, blue: 240.0/255.0, alpha: 0.5)

    //刪除多餘的隔線
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)

    self.tableView.separatorColor = UIColor(red: 240.0/255.0, green: 240.0/255.0, blue: 240.0/255.0, alpha: 1)

    //title = self.recipes.name

    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 36.0;
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;

    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self

    self.tableView2.delegate = self
    self.tableView2.dataSource = self

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    var cellNum:Int?

    if tableView == self.tableView {
        cellNum = 4
    }
    else if tableView == self.tableView2 {
        cellNum = 1
    }

    return cellNum!
}



func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


if(tableView == self.tableView) {
    let cell: DetailTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! DetailTableViewCell
    //cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    if self.category == 0 {
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            cell.fieldLabel.text = "名稱"
            cell.valueLabel.text = recipes.name
            cell.amountLabel.text = ""

        case 1:
            cell.fieldLabel.text = "類型"
            cell.valueLabel.text = recipes.type
            cell.amountLabel.text = ""

        case 2:
            cell.fieldLabel.text = "收藏"
            cell.valueLabel.text = (recipes.isFavor) ? "Yes" : "No"
            cell.amountLabel.text = ""

        case 3:
            cell.fieldLabel.text = "食材"
            cell.valueLabel.text = recipes.material
            cell.amountLabel.text = recipes.amount
        default:
            cell.fieldLabel.text = ""
            cell.valueLabel.text = ""
            cell.amountLabel.text = ""
        }
    }

    if self.category == 1 {
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            cell.fieldLabel.text = "名稱"
            cell.valueLabel.text = noodles.name
            cell.amountLabel.text = ""

        case 1:
            cell.fieldLabel.text = "類型"
            cell.valueLabel.text = noodles.type
            cell.amountLabel.text = ""

        case 2:
            cell.fieldLabel.text = "收藏"
            cell.valueLabel.text = (noodles.isFavor) ? "Yes" : "No"
            cell.amountLabel.text = ""

        case 3:
            cell.fieldLabel.text = "食材"
            cell.valueLabel.text = noodles.material
            cell.amountLabel.text = noodles.amount
        default:
            cell.fieldLabel.text = ""
            cell.valueLabel.text = ""
            cell.amountLabel.text = ""
        }
    }

    if self.category == 2 {
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            cell.fieldLabel.text = "名稱"
            cell.valueLabel.text = snacks.name
            cell.amountLabel.text = ""

        case 1:
            cell.fieldLabel.text = "類型"
            cell.valueLabel.text = snacks.type
            cell.amountLabel.text = ""

        case 2:
            cell.fieldLabel.text = "收藏"
            cell.valueLabel.text = (snacks.isFavor) ? "Yes" : "No"
            cell.amountLabel.text = ""

        case 3:
            cell.fieldLabel.text = "食材"
            cell.valueLabel.text = snacks.material
            cell.amountLabel.text = snacks.amount
        default:
            cell.fieldLabel.text = ""
            cell.valueLabel.text = ""
            cell.amountLabel.text = ""
        }
    }

    if self.category == 3 {
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            cell.fieldLabel.text = "名稱"
            cell.valueLabel.text = noodles.name
            cell.amountLabel.text = ""

        case 1:
            cell.fieldLabel.text = "類型"
            cell.valueLabel.text = noodles.type
            cell.amountLabel.text = ""

        case 2:
            cell.fieldLabel.text = "收藏"
            cell.valueLabel.text = (noodles.isFavor) ? "Yes" : "No"
            cell.amountLabel.text = ""

        case 3:
            cell.fieldLabel.text = "食材"
            cell.valueLabel.text = noodles.material
            cell.amountLabel.text = noodles.amount
        default:
            cell.fieldLabel.text = ""
            cell.valueLabel.text = ""
            cell.amountLabel.text = ""
        }
    }

    if self.category == 4 {
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            cell.fieldLabel.text = "名稱"
            cell.valueLabel.text = noodles.name
            cell.amountLabel.text = ""

        case 1:
            cell.fieldLabel.text = "類型"
            cell.valueLabel.text = noodles.type
            cell.amountLabel.text = ""

        case 2:
            cell.fieldLabel.text = "收藏"
            cell.valueLabel.text = (noodles.isFavor) ? "Yes" : "No"
            cell.amountLabel.text = ""

        case 3:
            cell.fieldLabel.text = "食材"
            cell.valueLabel.text = noodles.material
            cell.amountLabel.text = noodles.amount
        default:
            cell.fieldLabel.text = ""
            cell.valueLabel.text = ""
            cell.amountLabel.text = ""
        }
    }
    return cell
}
else if tableView == tableView2 {
    let cell: MaterialDetailTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell2") as! MaterialDetailTableViewCell
    //cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    if self.category == 0 {
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            cell.materialLabel.text = recipes.material
        default:
            cell.materialLabel.text = ""
        }
    }
    if self.category == 1 {
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            cell.materialLabel.text = noodles.material
        default:
            cell.materialLabel.text = ""
        }
    }
    if self.category == 2 {
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            cell.materialLabel.text = snacks.material
        default:
            cell.materialLabel.text = ""
        }
    }
    if self.category == 3 {
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            cell.materialLabel.text = noodles.material
        default:
            cell.materialLabel.text = ""
        }
    }
    if self.category == 4 {
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            cell.materialLabel.text = noodles.material
        default:
            cell.materialLabel.text = ""
        }
    }
    return cell
}
       //-----------------------this line appear error
}


//避免被前面一頁的隱藏導覽列所影響
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = false
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
}

/*
 // MARK: - Navigation

 // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
 // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
 // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
 }
 */
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You return nothing, when `tableView != self.tableView` and `tableView != tableView2`. That's why you see this error. If you are sure that this cannot be reached, try removing your `else if` condition

Answer (score 1):

Return the tableviewcell in `else`

```
 return UITableViewCell()
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you improve your answer by being more precise ? Maybe including a longer code example.

Answer (score 0):

Your only return is nested in an IF statement.  So if that is not satisfied, nothing is being returned.

Answer (score 0):

The error appears because no cell is returned when your "if" statement and your "else if" statement is not fulfilled. You have to either change your "else if" statement to just an "else" statement or return a cell in the line where your error happens as default cell.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return something `if` and `else if` is `false` too.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if(tableView == self.tableView) {
        //returning cell correctly
    } else if tableView == tableView2 {
        //returning cell correctly
    }
    //you need to return something here too
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your whole method has a structure like this:

```
if tableView == self.tableView {
    // blah blah blah
    return some stuff
} else if tableView == tableView2 {
    // blah blah blah
    return some stuff
}
```

So what if `tableView` is neither `self.tableView` nor `tableView2`? What if it is some other tableView? The code doesn't return anything!

Since the method is declared to return a `UITableViewCell`, you must not return nothing. That's why the error appears.

"But `tableView` can only be those two values! I promise!" you shouted.

But the swift compiler doesn't know that you promised.

If you are *really* sure, you can just write `fatalError("tableView is some other value")` at the end of the method, outside the if statement.

The advantage of this solution is that it can remind you, by crashing the app, that you forgot to add an `else if` clause to the method.

If you are absolutely sure that you will not add another table view, you can just change the `else if` to a simple `else`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, most of the time this happens with me too.

So, here is what you did.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


if(tableView == self.tableView) {
    let cell: DetailTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! DetailTableViewCell
    //Some code for cell
    return cell
}

else if tableView == tableView2 {
    let cell: MaterialDetailTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell2") as! MaterialDetailTableViewCell
    //Some code for cell
    return cell
}

//--> Compiler Says: What should I do if both are false. I need to return cell anyways. Please guide me.!!!!
//--> Solution : Return Cell from here as well 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend removing your `else if` condition, instead add an `else` condition with an assertion to alert you or someone that changed that code about this unexpected behaviour seems a better option.

If someone adds a new table view it needs to update this code and removing your `else if` will hide that fact.

```
if tableView == self.tableView {
    // ...
} else if tableView == tableView2 {
    // ...
} else {
    fatalError(" Unexpected behaviour: only 2 tables are supported")
    // Or any other assertion...    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = UITableViewCell()
        switch tableView {
        case yourTableView1:
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "yourTV1Cell", for: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.text = //your text here
        case yourTableView2:
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "yourTV2Cell", for: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.text = //your text here
        default:
            print("...what else") //...or write your default case here

        }
        return cell

    }
```